# React Native | Huawei App Galery Services?

Tags: react-native, huawei-mobile-services

I am developing an application with React native. The applications I made earlier do not work on new devices because Google Services is inactive. Huawei Develepor documents are not very clear. Is there a situation that shows how this is integrated? When I use a Map service, will AppleMap on iOS and GoogleMap on Android come out and HuaweiMap on these new Huawei phones?

Comment: Sorry, your question is very broad, can you narrow down what you're asking or provide more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app may have integrated GMS. As new Huawei phones are banned from using GMS, you app, if with GMS integrated, will be unable to run on new Huawei phones. If you want your app to run on these phones, integrate [Huawei Mobile Services (HMS)](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms).

For the documents about [Map Kit React Native integration](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050143001), find them here.

The integration is quick and easy. You can conveniently convert your code using [HMS Core ToolKit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/huawei-toolkit/).

If you want to use the map service in your app, and also want your app to run on both Huawei phones and Google Android phones, you can integrate both GMS Map Kit and HMS Map Kit. Then your app will use HMS Map Kit on Huawei phones, while using GMS Map Kit on Google Android phones.

Answer (score 1):

when you said do not work do you mean the map isn't showing? I believe for a react native app you'll have to separately implement the maps on all three platforms. Regarding integrating RN in Huawei environment you can refer to this https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topicview?tid=0201230857831870061&fid=0101187876626530001, or search in the forum which is pretty informative.

Answer (score 1):

To develop HMS Map with React Native you can refer the article
**"[HMS Map Kit Elucidated : Using React Native"](https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topicview?tid=0201267509735820036&fid=0101187876626530001)**

Hope this should helpful.